# Getting SKSpriteNode in a matrix when clicked

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit

In order to try both SpriteKit and Swift for OS X (not for iOS), I want to create a Minesweeper game.

All the logic behind the game is already done (and proved it works, I did it as a college project, but with a CLI interface), but where I'm having major problems is on the UI.

I have a 10x10 Tile matrix, and I'm not able to get the correct Tile after the user clicks the screen.

My code looks like this:

```
class Tile {
    var sprite: SKSpriteNode
    var isBomb: Bool
    var isUnlocked: Bool
    var row: Int
    var col: Int

    init(sprite: SKSpriteNode, row: Int, col: Int){
        // Default assignations
        self.sprite.name = "\(row):\(col)"
    }

}

class GameScene: SKScene {


    var board: [[Tile]] = [[Tile]]()
    let ROWS: Int = 10
    let COLS: Int = 10

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){

        for row in 0..<ROWS {
            board.append([Tile]())
            for col in 0..<COLS{
                var tileSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tile")

                var x: CGFloat = (tileSprite.size.height * CGFloat(row))+(tileSprite.size.height/2)
                var y: CGFloat = (tileSprite.size.width * CGFloat(col))+(tileSprite.size.width/2)

                tileSprite.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

                // I also add it here, just for ensuring that the name is set
                tileSprite.name = "\(row):\(col)"

                board[row].append(Tile(sprite: tileSprite, row: row, col: col))
                addChild(tileSprite)
            }
        }

    }

    func getRowColFromNode(node: SKSpriteNode) -> (row: Int, col: Int){

        var row: Int = 0
        var col: Int = 0

        /*var xPosition = node.position.x
        var yPosition = node.position.y

        row = Int(yPosition/node.size.height)
        col = Int(xPosition/node.size.width)*/

        if let name = node.name {

            println("NAME: \(name)")

            var rowString: String
            var colString: String

            var nameSplit = name.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

            rowString = nameSplit[0]
            colString = nameSplit[1]

            row = rowString.toInt()!
            col = colString.toInt()!


            println("DETECTEDROW: \(row)")
            println("DETECTEDCOL: \(col)")

        }


        return (row, col)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

        var touchedNode: SKSpriteNode = nodeAtPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow) as SKSpriteNode

        var row: Int
        var col: Int


        (row, col) = getRowColFromNode(touchedNode)

        println("ROW: \(row)")
        println("COL: \(col)") 

    }

}
```

I've even tried by dividing theEvent.locationInWindow.y / tile.sprite.size.width, but I'm never able to get the correct tile.

Sometimes I get the 12th row, or 15th column, or maybe a tile which is some tiles away from the point I clicked.

Also, I'm not able to disable the ability to resize the window.

Any help will be great, so thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the locations of the mouse clicks are in the view's coordinate system. You need convert them to scene coordinates to select the correct node. Here's an example of how to do that...

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    // Convert the mouse-down event's location to scene coordinates
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
```

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!

BTW, the "location" declaration should be location: CGPoint

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rethink your structure somewhat. Why not make your tiles a subclass of SKSpriteNode (instead of containing one)?

```
class TileSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    var isBomb: Bool // Perhaps use an enum for type instead as well?
    var isUnlocked: Bool
    var row: Int
    var col: Int

    init(row: Int, col: Int){
        // Default assignations
    }
}
```

Then in your setup:

```
for row in 0..<ROWS {
        board.append([Tile]())
        for col in 0..<COLS{
            var tileSprite = TileSprite(imageNamed: "tile")
            var x: CGFloat = (tileSprite.size.height * CGFloat(row))+(tileSprite.size.height/2)
            var y: CGFloat = (tileSprite.size.width * CGFloat(col))+(tileSprite.size.width/2)

            tileSprite.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            tileSprite.row = row
            tileSprite.col = col

            addChild(tileSprite)
        }
    }
```

and...

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow) as TileSprite
        let row = touchedNode.row
        let col = touchedNode.col

        println("ROW: \(row)")
        println("COL: \(col)") 
    }
```

You could also expand this to have the row/col as a tuple property of the TileSprite changed through a setter-method. This setter method could then have the responsibility to calculate the position of the sprite as well, cleaning up the scene-setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still getting some issues:

1.- When I click, I don't know why, but it detects the click in another zone of the screen, so I get the wrong tile.

2.- The SKSPriteNode subclassing was a little bit tricky, but I managed to solve it

3.- I've tried only printing the NSEvent.locationOnScreen, and it seems it's working well, but the nodeAtPoint() function doesn't return the correct Tile

Comment: Finally with 0x141E's answer I managed to solve the issue, but thank you for the optimization sugestion